# ListView with overlapping elements

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

What is better solution to implement such layout:[image]

I've tryid:

1. listview with negative divider (bad solution when rows need to have
   different height)
2. scroll view with relativelayout (bad solution
   because of memory consumption)
3. two listviews scrolling
   simultaniously (very bad)

Answer (score -1):

Create custom layout for listview items.

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/evenSideLayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/oddSideLayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Now in your custom Adapter... Manage layouts visibility. like

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_option_layout, parent,
                false);
        LinearLayout oddLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.oddLayout);
        LinearLayout evenLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.evenLayout);
        if(position%2==0)
        {
            evenLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            oddLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else
        {
            evenLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            oddLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: this is the worst option I think

Comment: did you try your solution? I think it will not work, because items allocated not row by row